# Problem with pymongo and django unique value

Tags: django, unit-testing, indexing, pymongo

I am writing django app that as a beckend is using mongodb. I am curently writing register part. Here is how I connecto to database in settings.py

```
if socket.gethostname() == "Production server":
    CON = Connection()
    DB = CON.fish
else:
    CON = Connection()
    DB = CON.test
DB.user.ensure_index([("username", ASCENDING),("email",ASCENDING)],unique = True)#,drop_dups=True
```

Here is mye register view:

```
def register(request):
    """
    handle user registration
    code variable is for testing purposes
    """
    if request.method== 'GET':
        form = RegisterForm(auto_id=False)
        code = 1
        return render_to_response('register_home.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            password_confirmation = form.cleaned_data['password_confirmation']
            if password == password_confirmation:
                login = form.cleaned_data['login']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                newsletter = form.cleaned_data['newsletter']
                key = register_user(login,email,password,newsletter)
                if key:

                    #send email
                    send_mail("Dziękujemy za rejestrację"," Klucz aktywacyjny to " + key,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[email])
                    request.session['email'] = email
                    return redirect(register_success)
                else:
                    code = 4
                    error = "Login/email taken"
                    return render_to_response('register_home.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                code = 3
                error  = "invalid password"
                return render_to_response('register_home.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            code = 2
            return render_to_response('register_home.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my function I use to register user:

```
def register_user(login,email,password,newsletter):
    """
    This function will return activation key for this user if user was added successfully or none otherwise
    """
    key = generate_activation_key()
    user = {
        "username":login,
        "email":email,
        "password":crypt_password(password),
        "date_join": datetime.now(),
        "key": key
    }
    if newsletter:
        user['newsletter'] = True
    try:
        settings.DB.user.insert(user,safe = True)
    except DuplicateKeyError, error:
        logging.debug("error raise during saving user")
        return None
    except OperationFailure, error:
        logging.critical("Cannot save to database")
        logging.critical(error)
    else:
        #we have no errors users is registred
        return key
```

And when I test it in the browser it seems to be working. But I write test for it and it isn't working anymore. Here is code for test:

```
def test_valid_credentials(self):
        #now try to register valid user
        data = {'login':'test','password':'zaq12wsx','password_confirmation':'zaq12wsx','terms':True,'newsletter':True,'email':'test@test.com'}
        response = self.c.post(reverse('register'),data)
        #our user should be registred
        self.assertEquals(302, response.status_code,'We dont have benn redirected')
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1,'No activation email was sent')
        #clen email box
        mail.outbox = []
        #now try to add another user with the same data
        response = self.c.post(reverse('register'),data)
        #template should be rendered with error message about used login and email
        self.assertEquals(200, response.status_code)#this fails
```

And here is error that i get.

```
    self.assertEquals(200, response.status_code)
AssertionError: 200 != 302
```

So user was registred with the same username and email which shoudn't happen. Any sugestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use https://github.com/django-mongodb-engine/mongodb-engine it works almost perfect with Django ORM. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: I don't want and need an ORM. Working with pymongo directly is fine for me and I am not building a huge website just simple hobbist project.